# What's the difference betwen once and double opening of "fstream" in c++ (In the fst case input doesn't working)?

Tags: c++, file, io

I have the file `"input file.txt"`:

```
Hello
```

I have the following code:

```
fstream ff;
ff.open("input file.txt");
ff.open("input file.txt", ios::in);
for (string s; ff >> s; cout << s)
    ;
```

which outputs:

```
<empty>
```

and the second code (there is one change):

```
fstream ff;
//ff.open("input file.txt");
ff.open("input file.txt", ios::in);
for (string s; ff >> s; cout << s)
    ;
```

which outputs:

```
Hello
```

The question is why?

Comment: Curious _why_ you would want to try opening a file twice with the same stream? What were you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: My classmate wrote this and asked me to find the mistake.

Comment: Why didn't they ask the teacher instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the stream is already associated with a file (i.e., it is already open), calling this function (`open()`) fails: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/

So your second call fails. Hence the result you get.